# Python / Pandas - Add a new record to a dataframe with a function

Tags: python, pandas

i'm new to Python / Pandas so this may be trivial but i really can't find the answer...

i'm trying to have a function **log_add_game()** to add new record to a dataframe **df_log_game** (for simplicity, i only keep the "time" column here)

Below are my code

```
import pandas as pd #datalist
from datetime import datetime as dt

df_log_game = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time']) # creates a log

def log_add_game():
    global df_log_game
    print("df_log_game")
    print(df_log_game)
    print('-----------------------')
    new_log = {
        'time': dt.now()
        }
    print("new_log")
    print(new_log)
    print('-----------------------')
    df_log_game = df_log_game.append(new_log, ignore_index=True)
    print("new df_log_game")
    print(df_log_game)
    print('-----------------------')

log_add_game()
print(df_log_game)
```

when i run the whole script, everything seem fine and i have 1 record in my **df_log_game**

but when i run the **log_add_game()** again, i have the following output

```
In[4]: log_add_game()
df_log_game
                        time
0 2022-07-24 00:32:34.312267
-----------------------
new_log
{'time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 24, 0, 37, 42, 592565)}
-----------------------
new df_log_game
                        time
0 2022-07-24 00:32:34.312267
1 2022-07-24 00:37:42.592565
-----------------------
```

when i think it works, i realize the function is updating sth else instead of my expected "**df_log_game**" as it still only have 1 record.

```
print(df_log_game)
                        time
0 2022-07-24 00:32:34.312267
```

the function seems updating another variable as if i keep runing it, it keep adding record to sth but my **df_log_game** still only have the initial record (and the Variable explorer only have 1 variable which is the one with 1 record too).

```
log_add_game()
df_log_game
                        time
0 2022-07-24 00:32:34.312267
1 2022-07-24 00:37:42.592565
2 2022-07-24 00:42:51.023733
-----------------------
new_log
{'time': datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 24, 0, 46, 6, 479812)}
-----------------------
new df_log_game
                        time
0 2022-07-24 00:32:34.312267
1 2022-07-24 00:37:42.592565
2 2022-07-24 00:42:51.023733
3 2022-07-24 00:46:06.479812
-----------------------

print(df_log_game)
                        time
0 2022-07-24 00:32:34.312267
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

For additional info, i can resolve the problem by rerun the def of "log_add_game()". no change to the code, just rerun

After that when i call "log_add_game()" again, it add the record to the global df_log_game as expected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think utilizing a global variable definition might be tripping you up.  Global variables within loops and functions can be tricky.  What you might try instead is passing the data frame as a parameter and receiving it back via a return from the function.  Following is a snippet of code showing how that might be done.

```
import pandas as pd #datalist
from datetime import datetime as dt

df_log_game = pd.DataFrame(columns=['time']) # creates a log

def log_add_game(internal_df_log_game):
    #global df_log_game
    #print("df_log_game")
    #print(df_log_game)
    #print('-----------------------')
    new_log = {
        'time': dt.now()
        }
    print("new_log")
    #print(new_log)
    #print('-----------------------')
    internal_df_log_game = internal_df_log_game.append(new_log, ignore_index=True)
    #print("new df_log_game")
    #print(df_log_game)
    #print('-----------------------')
    return internal_df_log_game

df_log_game = log_add_game(df_log_game)
df_log_game = log_add_game(df_log_game)  # Just to get a second entry into the data frame
print(df_log_game)
```

To reduce the printed data on the terminal, I commented out most of the "print" statements.  But also notice I commented out the "global" declaration within your function.  Instead, the function utilizes a data frame parameter passed into the function.  That data frame is appended and then returned which then updates your initial data frame.

Running the code resulted in the following output on my terminal.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/LogGame$ python3 LogGame.py 
new_log
LogGame.py:17: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  internal_df_log_game = internal_df_log_game.append(new_log, ignore_index=True)
new_log
LogGame.py:17: FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.
  internal_df_log_game = internal_df_log_game.append(new_log, ignore_index=True)
                         time
0  2022-07-23 12:34:22.362923
1  2022-07-23 12:34:22.440994
```

Hopefully, I haven't missed the mark as to your issue, but this tweak avoids using a "global" declaration.

Hope that helps.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks Man~ that works!
But i'm still confused on using the "global" declaration.
i have some other functions using global variable which don't update/get the latest value as i wanted...

would appreciate if someone can also tell me why the original code would have such behavior to help me understand more on using a "global" variable